# Is a medical evaluation required for Australia's eVisitor (subclass 651) visa?

Tags: visas, australia

I just applied for a 651 for my son to make his annual visit here from the UK, which is usually processed in a day or two. This time, however, they've requested that he get a medical exam and chest x-ray? Why?

We do this every year; the only difference now is that he's 18 years old and that I'm now an Australian citizen.

Has anyone else ever been requested to do this? Is it possible that it's a mistake? Surely they can't expect every holiday visitor to spend time and a large amount of money prior to a visit to Australia.

Comment: Is he a UK citizen?

Comment: Did your son state on the application form that he's lived in countries other than UK in the past year?

Answer (score 2):

The visa requirements state that an applicant must be free of tuberculosis when they enter. https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/651- The medical and x-ray will prove this, as they’ve requested it I doubt the visa will be approved without it.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but surely they don't get all UK holidaymakers off to the consultant prior to jumping on the Etihad express?

Comment: @Ste Hill How long is your son’s trip? Has he recently spent more than three consecutive months in a country with a high TB risk?

Comment: No, he lives in NW England and his only annual holiday is here, once a year, as he's done for the last 5 years running, except this time they're playing silly buggers

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa/heal/meeting-the-health-requirement/health-examinations) shows the circumstances where health examinations are required for visa applicants.  In particular, for temporary visas such as subclass 651, the requirement to conduct a health examination is dependent on factors including (emphasis added):

> - the type of visa that you are applying for
> - the length of your intended stay in Australia
> - your country level of tuberculosis risk
> - your intended activities in Australia
> - any *special circumstances* that might be applicable, and/or
> - the presence of any *significant medical conditions*.

As stated on that web page, the UK is a low-risk country, and ordinarily health examinations are not required.  However, there may be items disclosed in the visa application (e.g. travel history, studying or working in the healthcare or childcare industry, past health issues) which may trigger a health examination.